# Do we always worship only one god?

Tags: belief, worship

I heard the story about Draupadi - She called Krishna as VaikunthaVaasa(Dweller of Vaikuntha), then Krishna had to travel to Vaikuntha and come back to Draupadi. Again she called Him VrindavanaVaasa(Dweller of Vrindavana), and  Krishna had to travel to Vrindavana and come to Draupadi. Now Krishna got confused and said these words to Draupadi:

Call Me with one name, I will respond, but do not call Me with too names, I will ged confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that , "we always worship one god"

He himself the Supreme Paramatma manifests / assumes different forms himself . We can see this truth highlighted in our ancient Upanishads.

Here in the **Shvetashvatara Upanishad - Adhyaya 6 - Shloka 11** - it's said that there is only one god , who resides in the hearts of all the creatures.

> **एको देव**: सर्वभूतेषु गूढः सर्वव्यापी सर्वभूतान्तरात्मा। 
>   कर्माध्यक्ष: सर्वभूताधिवस: । साक्षी चेता केवलो निर्गुणश्च
>   ।।6.11।।
>
> **eko devaḥ** sarvabhūteṣu gūḍhaḥ 
> sarvavyāpī sarvabhūtāntarātmā 
>   karmādhyakṣaḥ sarvabhūtādhivāsaḥ  sākṣī cetā kevalo nirguṇaś ca ।।
>   6.11
>
> **He is the one without a second**, yet he is hidden in every being. He is
>   all pervasive, the Self of all. He gives to all beings the fruits of
>   their actions, and he is the support of all. He is the witness,
>   bestower of consciousness, without attributes and unconditioned.

---

Similarly in the **Mudgalopanishad  Khanda 3 - Shloka 1** - We  can clearly see the concept of One God .Here what it says-:

> **एको देवो** बहुधा निविष्ट अजायमानो बहुधा विजायते ।।3.1।।
>
> Eko Devo Bahuda Nivishta  Ajaayamano Bahuda Vijayaye
>
> **In this creation there is only one god** ,who is manifisted himself in
>   different forms . He himself being unborn , assumes different forms.
>   [image]

So no matter which god we worship, we worship only one Paramatma ,who is without second. i.e.non dual.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we always worship one god. In the Bhagavad Gita Krishna tells Arjun

> "Whatever a man may sacrifice to other gods, O son of Kunti, is really meant for Me alone, but it is offered without true understanding." **BG 9.23**.